# Filter Bank and Auto-Encoder

Tags: convolution, filter-bank, neural-network

I'm trying to find an intuition behind auto-encoder using an analogy with filter banks.

I can comprehend the encoder and analysis filters in a filter bank as extracting features from the input signal i.e. they represent the signal in more and more complicated features in deeper layers, and the original image is like a combination of those feature "basis". However I'm trying to get an intuition behind the reconstruction of the signal. The decoder and the synthesis filters only have a lower dimensional representation of these signals, usually which is very sparse, then how do the reconstruct intuitively?

Are the analysis and synthesis in a filter bank inverses of each other? In order to achieve the best reconstruction is there any relationship when choosing the synthesis filters? I don't think they can be inverses because they operate on different data, i.e. the synthesis filters get 0 padding which wasn't there originally, so perhaps an inverse would not provide the best reconstruction or will it?

Similarly, are the transposed convolutions in the decoder part of the auto-encoder inverse of the convolutions in the encoder? Some papers use the decoder as the literal transpose of the filters in the encoder. I don't think they both can be inverse operations right just like transpose of a matrix is not inverse unless in some particular scenarios? If the weights are not shared between the encoder and decoder, what exactly is the decoder trying to do? Is it really trying to learn the inverse of the encoder? Because if that's the case then there shouldn't be a need to have the decoder learn anything, we could simply always use decoder as the inverse of the encoder throughout the training and learning?

Is there a similarity in this sense between filter bank and auto-encoder?

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Really, I'm surprised it appears homework?! I'll include more details.